# exceve syscall is not working via payload

Tags: c, nasm, system-calls, execve, stack-smash

I am writing basic payload for execve syscall. In nasm the payload is:

```
global _start
  2 section .text
  3    _start:
  4     call payload
  5     db '/bin/sh', 0, 'aaaaaaaa', 0
  6     payload:
  7       mov rax,rsp
  8       mov rax, [rax]
  9       ;mov BYTE  [rax + 0x9], 0x0
 10       mov QWORD  [rax + 0x0a], rax
 11       ;mov BYTE  [rax + 0x12], 0x0
 12       ;mov QWORD  [rax + 0x13], 0x0
 13     mov rdi, rax
 14     lea rsi, [rax + 0x0a]
 15     mov rdx, 0x0
 16     mov rax, 0x0b
 17     int 0x80
 18     mov rax, 0x01
 19     mov rbx, 0x21
 20     int 0x80
```

The C file is:

```
char payload[] = "\xe8\x11\x00\x00\x00"
  2                 "\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00"
  3                 "\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x00"
  4                 "\x48\x89\xe0"
  5                 "\x48\x8b\x00"
  6                 "\x48\x89\x40\x0a"
  7                 "\x48\x89\xc7"
  8                 "\x48\x8d\x70\x0a"
  9                 "\xba\x00\x00\x00\x00"
 10                 "\xb8\xcb\x00\x00\x00"
 11                 "\xcd\x80"
 12                 "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00"
 13                 "\xbb\x21\x00\x00\x00"
 14                 "\xcd\x80";
 15 void main() {
 16   long *pointer;
 17   pointer = (long *)&pointer + 2;
 18   *pointer = (long)payload;
```

There are 2 syscall first one is execve and second is exit. First one is not executing but the second one is working. This file exits with status code 33.
I debugged this code in r2. I put debug point at first `int 0x80` The value in registers rdi, rsi and rdx seem correct, let me paste the exact values:

```
rdi = 0x5580de416045
:> ps @ rdi
/bin/sh
rsi = 0x5580de41604f
px @ rsi
0x5580de41604f  4560 41de 8055 0000
rdx = 0x00000000
```

So rdi holds the address of `/bin/sh`, rsi holds an address on which first address is address of `/bin/sh`, and rdx is null. But I don't think it's working even using strace I don't see this sycall.

Comment: You aren't terminating the `argv` array with a NULL pointer.

Comment: @o11c, Yes, I am modified the asm code, sorry for the confusion. You can verify this from the payload's third line `\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x61\x00`

Comment: You can't use int 0x80 in 64-bit programs (at least not with system calls that need pointers), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code.  You'll need to use the `syscall` interface instead and update your system call numbers accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @o11c that was one of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Nate and @o11c, there were couple of problems:

1. Instead of int 0x80 I should have used syscall, as I was using registers for 64bit like rdi instead of ebx to pass the first arguement. Changed that but it was still not working.
2. Initially I was using `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`, so the string length was 7 not 9, so the address of argv is address of string + 8 (7 for length and 1 for null character) not 0a (10 ).
3. As @o11c pointed out argv should end with NULL address. After argv[0] I just put NULL byte, but this is not sufficient the whole 8 bytes should be NULL because it's an address.

After this the code is working fine.